# Proper way to integrate WebRTC to Electron app?

Tags: webrtc, electron

I'm trying to develop a peer-to-peer desktop app with Electron and WebRTC which transfers only JSON data betwen peers. I ran into many libraries such as `PeerJs`, `node-crt` and `electron-webrtc` but I'm not sure what's the best way to properly integrate that, any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personaly, i have chosen https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC, which is an API pretty easy to setup. This is not relative to Electron, this is open source, there is no API key needed and it works pretty well! 
But to transfer JSON data you can just use websockets, because you will need it with webRTC for signalling anyway... (ok this is not a p2p solution)

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this post now, I would recommend https://github.com/feross/simple-peer, as it provides a simpler abstractionon top of webRTC and is actively maintained.  It appears that as of now, SimpleWebRTC has been deprecated.